# Проблема с тегом select

Tags: html, bootstrap, html-select

Мне нужно сделать выпадающий список, как на рисунке. Интересует меня то, как сделать такие оглавления, как на изображении ("по сторам", "по товару"), чтоб они не выпадали вместе с `option`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, выражаетесь "не совсем понятно". Попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: "чтоб они не выпадали вместе с option." - а что делали?

Comment: чтоб на месте оставались, а выпадали пункты меню option, как на рисунке

Comment: Placeholder задайте селекту. Может prompt .. точно не помню. Загуглите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо, я уже решил проблему, сделал по примеру, указанному по этой ссылке https://www.howtomake.com.ua/front/stilizaciya-vsex-elementov-form-s-pomoshhyu-css-i-jquery.html